# Apostrophe after number to differentiate quantity from year.

Tags: apostrophe

How to tell the difference between  1984 songs (a quantity) from 1984 songs (musics composed in that specific year)?  Is it correct to use 1984's songs?

thank you !!!

Comment: Yes. It is correct to use 1984's songs. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63759/possessive-apostrophe-use

Comment: If your goal is just to be clear, then you would reword you sentence. "Songs of 1984" vs "1,984 songs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are acceptable understandings of '1984 songs' but '1,984 songs' would only refer to an amount of songs and 'songs from 1984' would only be the year. '1984's songs' isn't *wrong* but it's an *odd* personification unless you've built up to it. To me, it'd sound more natural to be talking about 1984 as a year, mention this, mention that, and then mention 'its songs'...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is correct to use 1984's songs. Here is some more information from english language learners stack exchange.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63759/possessive-apostrophe-use

Answer (score 0):

You can talk (or write) about the 1,984 songs of the year 1984 or 1984's songs.  You might want to help the reader keep it all straight.  The 1,984 songs that came out in 1984. The songs of 1984 were especially ______.